# Como usar o new em SQL?

Tags: sql, trigger

Meu objetivo é: assim que inserir um elemento em `banco1.Clientes` o mesmo seja inserido em `banco2.Clientes` através de uma trigger. Caso esse elemento já esteja no banco, deve haver um update. Mas não consigo usar o `NEW` corretamente.
Código da trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER insereBanco1 AFTER INSERT
ON banco1.clientes FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    /* insercao */
    BEGIN
            IF (NEW.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM banco2.Clientes)) THEN
            INSERT INTO banco2.Clientes VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.nome, NEW.dat_nascimento, NEW.cpf, NEW.rg, NEW.endereco, 
            NEW.numero, NEW.bairro, NEW.cidade, NEW.estado, NEW.cep);
            ELSE
                UPDATE banco1.Clientes, banco2.Clientes SET banco2.Clientes.nome = banco1.Clientes.nome, 
                banco2.Clientes.dat_nascimento = banco1.Clientes.dat_nascimento, banco2.Clientes.cpf = banco1.Clientes.cpf,
                banco2.Clientes.rg = banco1.Clientes.rg, banco2.Clientes.endereco = banco1.Clientes.endereco, banco2.Clientes.numero = banco1.Clientes.numero, 
                banco2.Clientes.bairro = banco1.Clientes.bairro, banco2.Clientes.cidade = banco1.Clientes.cidade, banco2.Clientes.estado = banco1.Clientes.estado, banco2.Clientes.cep = banco1.Clientes.cep 
                WHERE banco1.Clientes.id = banco2.Clientes.id;
            END IF;
    END;
END;

$$
```

O erro:

```
Error Code: 1146. Table 'banco1.NEW' doesn't exist
```

Comment: SQL é a linguagem, e parece que seu problema é específico da linguagem. MySQL é o servidor em si.

Comment: Mude o INSERT para algo assim: INSERT INTO BANCO2.CLIENTES VALUES ( new.id, new.nome....) 

Retire a constraint da tabela CLIENTES, por enquanto, para você ver como os registros estão sendo inseridos. Quando estiver tudo correto habilite a constraint.

Comment: Reginaldo, boa tarde! Fiz as devidas alterações, e agora o erro é o 1442: "Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'clientes' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger."

Comment: Inseri a trigger modificada no topico

Answer (score 0):

Você está misturando o banco1 e o banco2 no update. Embora seja possível, é muito mais fácil de ler e implementar usando as variáveis do `NEW` que estão disponíveis dentro do escopo da trigger.

Remova todas as referências a `banco1.Clientes` do update e as substitua pelos valores equivalentes de `NEW`.

Algo como:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER insereBanco1 AFTER INSERT
ON banco1.clientes FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN    
    IF (NEW.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM banco2.Clientes)) THEN
      INSERT INTO banco2.Clientes VALUES (
        NEW.id, 
        NEW.nome, 
        NEW.dat_nascimento, 
        NEW.cpf, 
        NEW.rg, 
        NEW.endereco, 
        NEW.numero, 
        NEW.bairro, 
        NEW.cidade, 
        NEW.estado, 
        NEW.cep);
    ELSE
        UPDATE banco2.Clientes 
           SET banco2.Clientes.nome = NEW.nome, 
               banco2.Clientes.dat_nascimento = NEW.dat_nascimento, 
               banco2.Clientes.cpf = NEW.cpf,
               banco2.Clientes.rg = NEW.rg, 
               banco2.Clientes.endereco = NEW.endereco, 
               banco2.Clientes.numero = NEW.numero, 
               banco2.Clientes.bairro = NEW.bairro, 
               banco2.Clientes.cidade = NEW.cidade, 
               banco2.Clientes.estado = NEW.estado, 
               banco2.Clientes.cep = NEW.Clientes.cep 
        WHERE banco2.Clientes.id = NEW.id;
    END IF;
END;
```